# Using effects and exhaustMap not working as expected for login button

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx-effects

I have a login button where when the user clicks, an action is fired to the store. The action has an effect that makes an http call that then validates the user.

This doesn't seem to work in my app, however. I have a spinner that loads for one second (i.e. debounceTime(1000)) when a login call is triggered. When I test by clicking the login button multiple times, the login call seems to be refreshed thus causing the spinner duration to refresh. The expected behaviour is to have the user click the login button and if there are any calls made before the observable is returned from the first call all the interim ones should be cancelled.

**app.effects.ts**

```
@Effect()
  authenticateLogin$ = this.action$.pipe(
    ofType(AppActionTypes.SetAuthInfo),
    debounceTime(1000),
    exhaustMap((action: SetAuthInfo) => {
      const payload = action.payload;
      return this.authService
        .login(payload.username, payload.password)
        .pipe(
          map(response => {
            this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
            return new SetAuthInfoSuccess(response);
          }),
          catchError(error => {
            return of(new SetAuthInfoError(error));
          })
        )
```

Is my understanding of exhaustMap incorrect? Or am I missing something else?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code should work as expected. you understand exhaustMap. Did you check if it falls into catchError?

Answer (score 0):

The code you've shared seem to work, except I'm not sure how you rely on the `debounceTime()` thing. If you want to react only on first click in a 1s timespan -- you should use `throttleTime`.

[Heres a comparison of debounceTime vs throttleTime vs auditTime](https://observable-playground.github.io/gist/304b955e27ea88f622094b671cdfbb7b)

[image]

Though, if you want your `exhaustMap` inner call to last at least 1s -- I would advice you using a construction, like this:

```js
exhaustMap(payload=>{
  const oneSecondTimer = timer(1000);
  const request = this.authService.login(payload);
  return forkJoin(request, oneSecondTimer, r => r);
})
```

More on [`forkJoin`](https://observable-playground.github.io/rxjs/forkJoin/) and [`exhaustMap`](https://observable-playground.github.io/rxjs/exhaustMap/).

And an article on more [smart pausing techniques](https://medium.com/@kddsky/pauseable-observables-in-rxjs-58ce2b8c7dfd).

Hope this helps